# Snapd is downloading without my permission

Tags: snap, offline

One day, I noticed that my Internet is being used. After using `sudo nethogs` I found that package called `snapd` is downloading something from internet regularly without my consent. The only snap program that I have installed is VLC.

So, how to see **what things do/did `snapd` upload or download** or how to make `snapd` run in offline mode?

Comment: It probably downloaded an updated version of VLC. That's how snaps work, keeping always up to-date.

Comment: @user68186, so how to make it run in offline mode? I do not want to spend my packets to update snaps regularly.

Comment: Have you tried `journalctl -u snapd`?

Comment: Welcome to snap world! This is one of the reasons I uninstalled snapd.

Comment: @DKBose, nothing useful in the journal. Just states that it has started. There were also messages that there are no updates available for some packages. The one that wasn't mentioned is android-studio, so it's probably what's happening with my system. The download is huge, it must be android-studio.

Answer (score 5):

snapd does not have the ability to disable its autorefresh function. Merely the option to choose at what times of the day it can do it.

This is more of a workaround than a proper solution, but if VLC is the only snap you have, you can simply remove the snapd package and install VLC via the standard apt install method.

Though a matter of opinion, I prefer apt installing my software anyway, as it is more space efficient with disks. The downside would be possible dependency issues in some less common cases. Snaps eliminate this problem by having everything required for a particular program in one snap.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it may sound not professional, but I installed VLC via snap because an APT package contains some bugs which make me go crazy, such as when opening a video, the audio and image sequences got opened separately in different windows :(. However, snap package does not have this kind of bug...

Comment: I didnt want to uninstall snapd as it may be useful/important, I just wanted to disable it but the systemctl commands are not clear (saying nothing is running while snapd is there!). As it is spending my whole data quota of 100MB/day, apparently there seems to have no real problem so I will just uninstall it thx!